# Disallow an annotation based on another annotation

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I have an annotation that is applicable to type(i.e class level) and another annotation that is applicable to field variables. Is there a way to disallow the field annotation if the type annotation is already applied?

I am developing an AspectJ application which has pointcuts based on annotations. Currently, I have two annotations - @Trace and @TraceAll. @Trace is allowed for field variables and @TraceAll is allowed for types.

If @Trace is applied, I am using set() to trace writes to the field variable which it is applied to. If @TraceAll is applied, I use within() to trace all field variables and methods.

I don't want to duplicate the tracing if the user applies both annotations on a single class.

Comment: Not at compile time.

Comment: No.  But your annotation processor can flag incompatible annotations as an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please learn how to write questions here on SO or on any other platform. Show your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Otherwise you will not get help but close votes and angry comments. Let your code speak instead of trying to explain everything in words only, forcing people to make educated guesses about what the heck your problem could be.

Comment: @shmosel: Yes, you can at compile time. Also no need for annotation processor. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing your job here, providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is your free shot because you are new to SO, next time please do it by yourself:

**Marker annotations:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface TraceAll {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Trace {}
```

The first thing that comes to mind here is: Why do you need two annotations? Why not just one annotation `@Trace` which can be applied to both types and methods? Keep it simple, there is no additional value in having two annotations. If `@Trace` would be applied to a type, would it not be implicitly clear that you want to trace all methods in that class?

**Annotated classes + driver application:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

@TraceAll
public class SomeClass {
  public void doSomething() {
    foo();
    bar();
    zot();
  }

  @Trace
  public void foo() {}

  public void bar() {}

  @Trace
  public void zot() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public void doSomething() {
    foo();
    bar();
    zot();
  }

  @Trace
  public void foo() {}

  public void bar() {}

  @Trace
  public void zot() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().doSomething();
    new SomeClass().doSomething();
  }
}
```

Here I replicated your situation: While `Application` only uses method-level annotations, `SomeClass` mixes both annotation types.

**Original aspect:**

As you did not show any of your code, I have to guess what you did in your aspect. I assume it is something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Trace;
import de.scrum_master.app.TraceAll;

public aspect TraceAspect {
  before() : @target(TraceAll) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : @annotation(Trace) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

This would lead to the problem you described in your question:

**Console log for original aspect:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.zot())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.doSomething())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.bar())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.zot())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.zot())
```

We can see that both advices fire and `SomeClass.foo()` as well as `SomeClass.zot()` are logged twice. This is what you want to avoid, right?

Here is a way to trigger compile errors if users do it:

**Improved aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Trace;
import de.scrum_master.app.TraceAll;

public aspect TraceAspect {
  before() : @target(TraceAll) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : @annotation(Trace) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }

  declare error : execution(@Trace * (@TraceAll *).*(..))
    : "Don't combine @TraceAll and @Trace annotations"; 
}
```

Now class `SomeClass` does not compile anymore until the method annotations have been removed, leaving behind only the type annotation. In Eclipse it looks like this:

[image: Eclipse compile errors]

But actually there is a much simpler way to avoid double logging:

**Improved aspect, iteration 2:**

Just combine the two advices into one with logical OR via `||` operator.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Trace;
import de.scrum_master.app.TraceAll;

public aspect TraceAspect {
  before() : (@target(TraceAll) || @annotation(Trace)) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log for improved aspect, iteration 2:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.zot())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.doSomething())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.bar())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.SomeClass.zot())
```

See? No more double logging without forcing users to play by rules you impose on them. Why not use both types of annotations? Maybe a developer always wants to trace certain methods. For debugging she adds a type-level annotation temporarily without wanting to be forced to remove all method-level ones because she could forget to add them again later.

**Iteration 3: only one annotation**

Now how about just using one annotation like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface Trace {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@Trace
public class SomeClass {
  public void doSomething() {
    foo();
    bar();
    zot();
  }

  @Trace
  public void foo() {}

  public void bar() {}

  @Trace
  public void zot() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Trace;

public aspect TraceAspect {
  before() : (@target(Trace) || @annotation(Trace)) && execution(* *(..)) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

The result will be the same.